# How can count button click?

Tags: python, tkinter, button, count, click

I want to count and write in csv file. In the first column i want to write count of button, and on the other button I want to write text. I create a function to write in csv. I use tkinter for GUI

```
def functie2(l, m):
    with open('employee_file3.csv', 'a+', newline = "\n") as csv_file:
     
        global click
        click += 1
        print(click)


        writer = csv.DictWriter(csv_file, fieldnames=fieldnames)
                
        writer.writerow({'Nr_crt': l, 'Prelucrare': m})

class Pag4(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        label = tk.Label(self, text="Alege prelucrarea")
        label.pack(pady=10,padx=10)
        self.controller = controller
        label = tk.Label(self, text="Pagina 4")
        button = tk.Button(self, text="Srunjire", command=lambda: [functie2('l', 'Strunjire'), controller.show_frame("Pag20")])
      
        button.pack()
```

Comment: what exactly doesn't work? You should define `click` outside the function

Comment: I don't know exactly how writing to `csv` works but it doesn't seem like You are writing `click` to that file

Answer (score 1):

You need to initialize `click` in the global scope.  If you want the first column inside the CSV file be the number of clicks, you should replace `l` by `click` and don't need to pass `l` to `functie2()`:

```py
click = 0   # initialize click

def functie2(m):
    global click
    with open('employee_file3.csv', 'a+', newline="\n") as csv_file:
        click += 1
        print(click)

        writer = csv.DictWriter(csv_file, fieldnames=fieldnames)
        writer.writerow({'Nr_crt': click, 'Prelucrare': m})

class Pag4(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        ...
        button = tk.Button(self, text="Srunjire", command=lambda: [functie2('Strunjire'), controller.show_frame("Pag20")])
        button.pack()
```

I would suggest to move `functie2()` into `Pag4` class so that you can use instance variable instead of global variable:

```py
class Pag4(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        label = tk.Label(self, text="Alege prelucrarea")
        label.pack(pady=10, padx=10)
        self.controller = controller
        self.click = 0
        label = tk.Label(self, text="Pagina 4")
        button = tk.Button(self, text="Srunjire", command=lambda: [self.functie2('Strunjire'), controller.show_frame("Pag20")])
        button.pack()

    def functie2(self, m):
        self.click += 1
        print(self.click)

        with open('employee_file3.csv', 'a+', newline="\n") as csv_file:
            writer = csv.DictWriter(csv_file, fieldnames=fieldnames)
            writer.writerow({'Nr_crt': self.click, 'Prelucrare': m})
```